# Count ISO_WEEK between two dates (potentially spanning across years)

Tags: sql, sql-server, iso, week-number

This may be a fairly simple question but I can't find a simple solution anywhere. Is there a way to count ISO_WEEK between two dates (which also may span over multiple years) without subtracting the ISO_WEEK values themselves?

If I subtract the number of ISO weeks between the below I get -47
2024-12-01 = W48
2024-12-31 = W01
The expected result should be 5

If I subtract the number of ISO weeks between the below I get -47
2022-01-01 = W52
2022-01-31 = W05
The expected result should be 6

If I subtract the number of ISO weeks between the below I get 0
2022-01-01 = W52
2022-12-31 = W52
The expected result should be 53

If I subtract the number of ISO weeks between the below I get -3
2022-12-31 = W01
2023-01-26 = W04
The expected result should be 5

Here is two portions of SQL I am using to test:
*The intention here is to calculate number of ISO weeks in the previous month for billing purposes. A condition has been added to remove 1 week from previous month should the week have already been billed in the previous iteration using conditional logic surrounding the first Sunday of that month.*

```
DECLARE @D DATE = '2025-01-01'

SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0) AS FOM
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)) AS FOM_ISOWEEK#
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @D)-1, -1))-DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0))+1 AS ISOWEEK_COUNT
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @D)-1, -1)) AS EOM_ISOWEEK#
        , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @D)-1, -1) AS EOM
        , DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 0 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0))), 6) AS FSUNDAY
        , CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)), (DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 0 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,    @D)-1, 0))), 6)))+1 < 7
                THEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @D)-1, -1))-DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0))
                ELSE DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @D)-1, -1))-DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0))+1 END AS [SUM]
```

```
DECLARE @DD DATE = '2022-02-01'

SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0) AS FOM
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0)) AS FOM_ISOWEEK#
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @DD)-1, -1))-DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0))+1 AS ISOWEEK_COUNT
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @DD)-1, -1)) AS EOM_ISOWEEK#
        , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @DD)-1, -1) AS EOM
        , DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 0 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0)), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0))), 6) AS FSUNDAY
        , CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0)), (DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 0 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0)), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,  @DD)-1, 0))), 6)))+1 < 7
                THEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @DD)-1, -1))-DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0))
                ELSE DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @DD)-1, -1))-DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DD)-1, 0))+1 END AS [SUM]
```

Everything works except when the subtraction spans over multiple years. I have provided two examples of this occurence above.

**UPDATE**
I have simplified somewhat and found a reasonable workaround [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/604052a8-b024-41a5-8bac-1c657d9f6025/calculate-number-of-weeks-between-dates?forum=transactsql). Updated logic below:

```
DECLARE     @D DATE = '2025-01-01'
            
DECLARE     @FOM DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)
            , @EOM DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @D)-1, -1)

SELECT  @FOM AS FOM
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,@FOM) AS FOM_ISOWEEK#
        , DATEDIFF(dd,0,@EOM)/7 - DATEDIFF(dd,0,@FOM)/7 +1 AS ISOWEEK_COUNT
        , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,@EOM) AS EOM_ISOWEEK#
        , @EOM AS EOM
        , DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 0 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0))), 6) AS FSUNDAY
        , CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)), (DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 0 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @D)-1, 0)), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,    @D)-1, 0))), 6)))+1 < 7
                THEN DATEDIFF(dd,0,@EOM)/7 - DATEDIFF(dd,0,@FOM)/7
                ELSE DATEDIFF(dd,0,@EOM)/7 - DATEDIFF(dd,0,@FOM)/7 +1 END AS [SUM]
```

This update produces the desired output.

Comment: using an interval of ISO weeks seems a bit strange and not that useful due to the way it diffs at the end of year, as you have discovered.

Comment: @MitchWheat Tell me about it, billing "per week or part thereof" has it's drawbacks unfortunately this is the business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/604052a8-b024-41a5-8bac-1c657d9f6025/calculate-number-of-weeks-between-dates?forum=transactsql

This helped. I have edited my question with an UPDATE to show it in use.

Comment: I am glad you found an answer. Instead of putting the answer into your request, you should put it here. Then you have a proper request and a proper answer that you can even accept. This may help future readers, because thus question and answer are separated as they should be. Anyway, thank your for putting so much effort into showing your solution here.